# is possible Bullet 3D on Gazebo?

Tags: gazebo

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Hi, i'm working with ROS, and Gazebo, and i'm working on colission detection , and now i'm wanna go one step more, i mean, make deformation between objects. I know that exist a library Call BUllet 3D and is used for Gazebo_plugins i suppose it's working with collision part, but it's possible make something or add the functions on bullet about deformable on Gazebo? how can i do that?

thnks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/1752/is-possible-bullet-3d-on-gazebo?/) by [monidiaz](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/124/monidiaz/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 3 on 2013-03-12

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Hi,

Bullet is integrated starting Gazebo 1.5, but no deformable objects yet. See [answer](http://answers.gazebosim.org/question/1724/gazebo-15-new-version-new-features/)..

Read [here](http://gazebosim.org/wiki/Tutorials/1.5/bullet) about what is implemented in version 1.5 .

Cheers,
Andrei

---

Originally posted by [AndreiHaidu](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/87/andreihaidu/) with karma: 2108 on 2013-03-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1